# Spring Standalone not recognizing @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, persistence

Recently, I integrated Spring into my Jboss application.  I am also putting together a standalone application that will use some of the Spring service classes.  Here is my Standalone source:

```
@Component
public class StandaloneTest {

public static ApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(StandaloneSpringBeanConfiguration.class);
    StandaloneTest test = context.getBean(StandaloneTest.class);
    System.out.println(context);
    test.startProcess();
}

public StandaloneTest() {

}

/**
 * Start the main process
 */
private void startProcess() {
        run();
}

private void run() {
    TestService testService = context.getBean(TestService.class);
    testService.transactionalTest();
    System.out.println("finished");
}
```

Here is the source for TestService:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

public GeneralDAO generalDAO;

private EntityManager em;

private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public TestServiceImpl(){}

    @Transactional
public void transactionalTest() {
    Something something = new Something();
    getEntityManager().persist(something);
} 

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (em == null) {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xxx");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
    return em;
} 


}
```

When I run this method in my Jboss server, the @Transactional annotation works as expected.  However, when I run the standalone application, the @Transactional annotations seems to be ignored.  I can't figure out why.

If anyone knows what I need to do to get this to work or has any ideas/comments, please share.  Thanks!

**Update**

Here's my Config file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class StandaloneSpringBeanConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setPersistenceUnitName("myPersistenceContext");
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "xxx.xxx.xxx"});

      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
   //   em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

      return em;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource(){
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jboss_test");
      dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
      dataSource.setPassword( "root" );
      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
          JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
          transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
          return transactionManager;
    }


   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }
```

**More Updates**

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

public GeneralDAO generalDAO;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public TestServiceImpl(){}

@Transactional
public void transactionalTest() {
Something something = new Something();
em.persist(something);
} 

}
```

This is definitely moving me in the right direction.  I'm getting this error now: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'

I'm having trouble figuring out the cause, but is the issue my choice of transactionManager?  I was reading somewhere that I need to use JOTM or Atomikos for standalone, but I don't think JOTM can be used in Spring 4 and Atomikos requires me to use Maven, which is not an option for me. Using the JTATransactionManager gave me the same result.

**Working Solution**

The JTA error seemed to resolve itself this morning.  Not sure what happened.  I then had to make sure that all the necessary packages were being scanned by LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean because I was getting an IllegalArgumentException Unknown Entity

Config

```
public class StandaloneSpringBeanConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xxx"});

      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
   //   em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

      return em;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource(){
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jboss_test");
      dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
      dataSource.setPassword( "root" );
      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
       return transactionManager;
    } 


   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }
```

Service Class

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

public GeneralDAO generalDAO;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public TestServiceImpl(){}

@Transactional
public void transactionalTest() {
Something something = new Something();
em.persist(something);
} 

}
```

Comment: What transaction manager do you have configured for Spring?

Comment: I added my Config file, see above - sorry, shoulda posted that to begin with.  At the moment, I'm using JpaTransactionManager.  In my jboss, I am using jtaTransactionManager.

Comment: Ofcourse it is ignored. You are configuring a `EntityManagerFactory` and aren't using it. Basically your whole configuration is useless. Remove the `getEntityManager()` method and put `@PersistenceContext` on the `private EntityManager` field. Which is how you are supposed to get an `EntityManager` in the first place. Your code is also dangerous as you are only getting an `EntityManager` once and not a transactional bound one.

Comment: You probably have set the type of resource manager in your `persistence.xml` to `JTA` however you aren't using that due to the `JpaTransactionManager` and the question is do you really need it. Set it to `LOCAL` and if you don't need distributed transactions (i.e. multiple transactional resources) you can leave it like that.

Comment: Got it working.  I didn't have any of that in my persistence.xml.  I don't think I changed anything, but it started working.  Not sure what happened there or what I did.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are working fine, they simply don't work in your setup. This is because you are working around a transactional bound `EntityManager` due to the fact you are recreating it.

Basically the code for your `TestServiceImpl` is flawed. You should remove the `getEntityManager()` method and instead annotate the `EntityManager` field with `@PersistenceContext`.

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

  public GeneralDAO generalDAO;

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public TestServiceImpl(){}

    @Transactional
    public void transactionalTest() {
      Something something = new Something();
      em.persist(something);
    } 
}
```

That is all you should need.

Comment: Correct, and here is why. `Transactional` only works with a *Container Managed EntityManager*, meaning one that is injected by Spring (or JavaEE) using `@PersistenceContext`. If you have an *Application Managed EntityManager*, meaning one where you create it from calling `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`, then your code is responsible managing the transactions, and calling `EntityManager.getTransaction().begin()` and `EntityManager.getTransaction().commit()`

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys.  I posted some updates above with a follow up question.  Side note- Klaus, I actually have been able to use EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager in the past without explicitly beginning or committing transactions.  I just used annotations.